# How do I find the most popular stories on FanFiction.net?

Tags: website

Is there a published/up to date list somewhere of stories by some sort of popularity ranking?

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obebokhpdpocfdindfhgliohbceeiabd